# Как оформить реферальную систему в боте в вк на vkbottle python?

Tags: python, вконтакте

Есть ссылка [https://vk.com/write-{сообщество}?ref_source={id}](https://vk.com/write-%7B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%7D?ref_source=%7Bid%7D)
Нужно отследить кто перешёл и написать человеку в {id}. Вот только знаний мне для этого не хватает, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по документации VK API [про `ref` и `ref_source`](https://vk.com/dev/bizmessages_doc?f=2.6.%20%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E%20%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8%20vk.me), эти поля возвращаются в виде строк в соответствующих полях объекта сообщения. Тогда c `vkbottle` это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```py
from vkbottle import Bot, Message

bot = Bot("token")

@bot.on.message()
async def ref_handler(m: Message):
    await bp.api.messages.send(
        peer_id=int(message.ref_source),
        message="some message"
    )
```